# How to "push out "XYZ coordinates forming a 3D orbit with an offset in the middle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, coordinates

I have a orbit of length 200. But it is centered around a sun of radius 0 (length 0). Now I want to expand the sun to have a radius of 1 and "push" out the outer orbits as well.

The XYZ coordinates look like this:

```
    [-6.76, 5.75, -1.06],
    [-6.95, 5.54, -0.91],
    [-7.13, 5.33, -0.75],
    [-7.31, 5.11, -0.58]
    ... followed by  196 more coordinates
```

I tried tried a lot of things to make the circle bigger `* radius` and `/ someNumbers`. To at least try to do it myself.
But i lost it when i made an `if` like this:

```
If(the x coordination > 0)
  the x coordination += 1;
}
Else{
the x coordination += 1;
}
```

And also for Y and Z but when they came close to the  1 and -1 position of that axis they skipped to the other side.
Creating a line (with the width of 1 on both sides) of emptiness along the axis.

Result of MBo's awnser(view from above):
[image]

```
// arrayIndex is a number to remember at which point it is in the orbit array
    satellites.forEach(function (element) {
                    if (element.arrayIndex>= element.satellite.coordinates.length) {
                        element.arrayIndex= 0;
                    }

                    var posX = element.satellite.coordinates[element.arrayIndex][0];
                    var posY = element.satellite.coordinates[element.arrayIndex][1];
                    var posZ = element.satellite.coordinates[element.arrayIndex][2];

                    R = Math.sqrt(posX^2 + posY^2 + posZ^2);

                    cf = (R + earthRadius) / R;
                    xnew = posX * cf;
                    ynew = posY * cf;
                    znew = posZ * cf;

                    // var posX = earthRadius * (element.satellite.coordinates[element.test][0] / (200 * earthRadius) * earthRadius);
                    // var posY = earthRadius * (element.satellite.coordinates[element.test][1] / (200 * earthRadius) * earthRadius);
                    // var posZ = earthRadius * (element.satellite.coordinates[element.test][2] / (200 * earthRadius) * earthRadius);


                    // divide by 100 to scale it down some more
                    element.position.x = xnew / 100;
                    element.position.y = ynew / 100;
                    element.position.z = znew / 100;

                    element.arrayIndex= element.arrayIndex+ 1;
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have orbit radius

```
/////////R = Sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
Edit to avoid confusion:
R = Sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)
```

You need to modify coordinates to make orbit radius `R+r`. To preserve orbit form, for every point find it's R, and multiply all components by coefficient `(R+r)/R`

```
R = Sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
cf = (R + r) / R
xnew = x * cf
ynew = y * cf
znew = z * cf
```

Comment: it partially works, it does grow, but it disappears when its between 2 axis, i added a image in the question. (the white line is side it does show)

Comment: It is strange. Are you sure in calculations? Check cf values. Show code that causes this behaviour

Comment: I plotted the arrays in python before I wanted to use them in javascript and they looked fine. i added the code that is used to make them go to the next position. when it disappears the cf = NaN. and when it is visible it makes a little dent when it is in the middle

Comment: You have used my mathematical writing, but `^` is xor operator, not power operator in Javascript!!! Replace with `R = Math.sqrt(posX*posX + posY* posY+ posZ*posZ);`  Javascript allows to shoot your foot :)